# Ошибка "the filesystem size (according to the superblock) is blocks" при загрузке виртуальной машины в ESXI

Tags: linux, esxi, fsck

При загрузке виртуальной машины в ESXI выскакивает ошибка:

```
the filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 30407680 blocks
the physical size of the device is 6553600 block
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt
```

Пробовал запустить fsck, но он говорит, что есть ошибки и предлагает их игнорировать и в результате ничего не делает.
Стоит LVM.
Что делалось до возникновения проблемы:

1. Был увеличен размер диска LVM
2. Включалась поддержка виртуализации
   После перезагрузки возникла эта ошибка.